# How can I develop with Expo via create-react-native-app on a network I don't control?

Tags: react-native, expo

I live at an apartment complex where the only option for internet is what's provided by the complex, which seems to have security settings that prevent a lot of stuff on the network.

Is it possible to use an Expo workflow to test a native iPhone app over a network if I can't manage the security settings of the router? If not, are there any feasible alternatives? (Aside from using cellular which doesn't allow hot reloads)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Expo XDE](https://github.com/expo/xde/releases/tag/v2.24.4). You can open the very same project created in create-react-native-app and the server that is run will allow you to connect directly over the wifi network seemingly regardless of security settings. It's as simple as installing the tool and opening the project.